# How can I display two elements of two list?

Tags: c#, list, object, unity-game-engine

So im making a Wheel of fortune, and have a list of prize and a list of the image of the prize, so i want to display the prize with the prize image at the end. I manage to display the prize but not the prize image. (the display is on a panel that activates when the wheel stop spinning)

here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class SpinWheel : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<string> Premio = new List<string>();
public List<AnimationCurve> animationCurves;
public List<GameObject> ImagenPremio = new List<GameObject>();
public Text itemNumberDisplay;
private bool spinning;
private float anglePerItem;
private int randomTime;
private int itemNumber;
public GameObject RoundEndDisplay;
void Start()
{
    spinning = false;
    anglePerItem = 360 / Premio.Count;
    itemNumberDisplay.text = "";
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !spinning)
    {
        randomTime = Random.Range(1, 4);
        itemNumber = Random.Range(0, Premio.Count);
        float maxAngle = 360 * randomTime + (itemNumber * anglePerItem);
        StartCoroutine(SpinTheWheel(5 * randomTime, maxAngle));
    }
}
IEnumerator SpinTheWheel(float time, float maxAngle)
{
    spinning = true;
    float timer = 0.0f;
    float startAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
    maxAngle = maxAngle - startAngle;
    int animationCurveNumber = Random.Range(0, animationCurves.Count);
    Debug.Log("Animation Curve No. : " + animationCurveNumber);
    while (timer < time)
    {
        //to calculate rotation
        float angle = maxAngle * 
animationCurves[animationCurveNumber].Evaluate(timer / time);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, angle + startAngle);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return 0;
    }
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, maxAngle + startAngle);
    spinning = false;
    Debug.Log("Premio: " + Premio[itemNumber]);
    if (spinning == false)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        RoundEndDisplay.SetActive(true);
        itemNumberDisplay.text = ("Premio: " + Premio[itemNumber]);

    }
   }
}
```

I would be glad if anyone can help!

Comment: your variable `spinning` seems like a waste of space. Since `Update` is only called once, it doesn't actually do anything right now. I can see how it could be useful if `Update` and `SpinTheWheel` ran in parallel though. But that would also require changing how you used it.

Comment: is ImagenPremio your list of image rewards? Are they all hidden gameobjects with sprites attached to them? why not just use `ImagenPremio[itemnumber].SetActive(true);`

Comment: I don't think I am understanding your question. Simple put the `setActive` part right after the `itemNumberDisplay.text;`

Comment: @ryemoss Thank YOU so much! I made a diferent panel for each prize with  the image an the text so it would display both at the same time, you just save my life, I waste 3 days searching a way an it was so simple!!!

Comment: just one last question @ryemoss , so your way works but it keeps the last prize and the new one, how can i disable the last prize?     'using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Boton : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool restart;
    public GameObject RoundEndDisplay;
    public List<GameObject> ImagenPremio = new List<GameObject>();
    private int itemNumber;

    public void Clicked()
    {
        RoundEndDisplay.SetActive(false);
        ImagenPremio[itemNumber].SetActive(false);
    } 

}'

Comment: yes. you can do `SetActive(false)`.

Comment: i try that code as this is the one that disable the main RoundEndDisplay, but is not working

Comment: Two lists? How about one list and a custom class? `List<Prize>...`, `public class Prize { string name; Sprite image; }`

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s manage to make a list of gameobjects and make multiples panels with the name and image of the prize so i could activate when i get a prize as ryemoss said but now i cant disable them using SetActive(false); and i dont know why

Comment: No idea `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

Use Dictionary to store prizes and images data. 
You can get values like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, GameObject> Premio;


private void Show(int itemNumber)
{
    Debug.Log("Premio: " +
              Premio.Keys.ToList()[itemNumber] +
              Premio[Premio.Keys.ToList()[itemNumber]);

}

private void ShowAll()
{
    foreach(var key in Premio.Keys)
    {
          Debug.Log("Premio: " + key + Premio[key]);
    }
}
```